# Material Node Problem

Tags: materials, node-editor

I want color from one image and texture from another image for the material of the dress I am working on. Currently I am using a mix shader to join the two images but I am not getting the desired result.

Below is an image with the color I want (I set the mix factor to 0):[image]

Below is an image with the texture I want (I set the mix factor to 1):

[image]

Is there any way I can get 100% of both effects. I don't want any color from the second image and changing from color to non-color data in Image Texture Node doesn't seem to do much.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll add my blender file in case it helps.

[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but you shouldn't be plugging green outputs (shader) into yellow inputs (colour).

Comment: yeah sorry I was just playing around with the nodes hoping the problem would suddenly disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mix node is for mixing different shaders, or materials, not different parts of one material. To add the "Texture" effect you want, I took a look at your file and reconfigured your shader to use a **Bump** node.

First, within the Chocofur_Fabric_Basic material, I removed the overlay node (unnecessary) and replaced it with a Bump node, routing the Main_Color input directly to the shaders and the Bump into their respective Normal inputs.

[image: 1]

Back in your main material node setup, I removed redundant nodes and hooked the sideways skirting color into the **Main_Color** input of the fabric shader and the Chocofur texture image into the **Texture_Input** input of the fabric shader.

[image: 2]

Here is the final Blend file:

[image]